# do i need to check if the token expired or refresh it when using parse to login Facebook user on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm fixing bugs in an iOS app that uses parse and the Facebook login. i'm seeing code that i think is fishy, but i figured i'd check first. I have not found an answer googling, but if i missed it, feel free to point it out.

The first thing the old code was doing was to check if the Facebook token was expired. Is this needed when using PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser to check the current user is the correct one?

The second thing the code was doing is to try to refresh the token (FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken). Would parse not take care of that?

And lastly the old code set an observer for FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification and called PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken which caused the PFUser.isNew to be false even for new signup. Is observing FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification required when using parse of is the parse SDK taking care of updating this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you resolve this question? maybe answer it :D

Comment: @MehdiAbderezai, I did not get an actual answer, but from what i gathered on that project, i don't think it this is needed, i think it's already done automatically.